# localhost/phpinfo.php

Tags: php, ubuntu, oauth

I have installed [php oauth](http://djpate.com/2010/10/07/how-to-install-oauth-support-for-php-on-ubuntu/) extension in ubuntu 110.10.

But on `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` in google chrome it is giving  the following error:

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/phpinfo.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

This means i am giving link to localhost then getting this error.

And in mozilla it is giving a blank screen.

It is not providing any information about installtion in php
How do i resolve this problem?

Comment: i am giving address localhost/phpinfo.php

Comment: Check if 
1. localhost is working?
2. place some simple php file (e.g., echo Hello) in your webroot, and see if it works fine.

Comment: The path should be localhost/someFolder/phpinfo.php

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem in your php.ini which is not letting  php to be loaded correctly!

Comment: @asprin: Why should the path be like that? I have such a script placed in my web root and it works like that.

Comment: My apologies. That path is for Windows. Didn't notice the 'Ubuntu' word

Comment: Even in "windows" (meaning IIS) you can set it up as you like. localhost can just point to some webroot, no problem.

Comment: It means there was a problem either on the webserver or with your PHP script. Check the error logs for the webserver and PHP.

Comment: If you are using apache, your error logs should be in /var/logs/apache2 normally.

Comment: It may be permission error.. Please check your folder permissions. Bcz, Most of Ubuntu (linux) users can face this type of error..

Comment: Where should you stored your PHP files and your php.ini config file? Please update the additional details with your question.

Comment: ok thanks problem solved .i was nt able to access file  ...............   sudo chmod 0777 -R /var/www/phpinfo.php i was able to see whole phpinformation

Comment: Welcome @user1556810.. If you are satisfied with my answer please vote up and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem but the reason was because I had just restored my files into www from a Windows NTFS backup drive.

Naturally, with NTFS we don't have the same permissions of Ubuntu or any other Linux system.

Looking at the folders using nautilus showed incorrect owners and permissions.

How I fixed it...

1. Took ownership of my /var/www folder and its contents by doing this: `chown khalid -R /var/www`
2. Changed the mode of the www containing files like this: `sudo chmod 644 -R /var/www`
3. If you still get errors, do this: `gksudo nautilus`. Then go into your /var/www folder and change the permissions to allow owner/group read/write and check the box to execute as program. Also apply this to the sub-folders.

**NOTE:** Never give 777 permissions to a web folder/file. That's like keeping your front door key hanging in the front of your gate! However, if this is a machine that never sees the daylight of Internet, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

It may be permission error.. Please check your folder permissions. Bcz, Most of Ubuntu (linux) users can face this type of error.

by the author of question:

```
sudo chmod 0777 -R /var/www/phpinfo.php
```